# round up the bc scale instead of round down with scale or printf

Tags: bash, shell, expression, sh, bc

I am using bc and scale for evaluating a expression however I want it to round up instead of round down. What is the simplest way to do this?

```
$ read exp
5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7
$ echo "scale=3; $exp" | bc -l
17.928
```

However my desired answer is `17.929`

I prefer the answer to be an addendum to my answer than something different ground up. Thanks

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
$ echo "scale=4; ($exp+0.0005)" | bc -l
17.9290
$ echo "scale=3; ($exp+0.0005)" | bc -l
17.9285
```

However I want `17.929` as answer with no zero at the end.

Comment: @dimo414 I don't want to write a function. I saw that before writing this

Comment: You don't need to write a function if you don't want to. The answer - to pipe into `printf` - is what the function does.

Comment: @MonaJalal: If you write (or copy) the function and put it into your bash startup file, it will always be there waiting for you. Otherwise, you end up having to type *something* long and complicated everytime you want the correctly rounded answer. Seriously, go with the bash function. Call it `bc` if you like.

Answer (score 7):

solved it by using `scaling factor` of `printf` as `3`, `scaling factor` of `bc` as `4` and adding `0.0005` to the expression:

```
printf "%.3f\n"  $( echo "scale=4; $exp+0.0005" | bc -l )
```

Comment: You don't need to add the `0.0005`, `printf` does the rounding properly. You can actually skip the `scale` step completely, this would work just as well: `printf "%.3f\n" $(bc -l <<< "$exp")`

Comment: @BenjaminW. that worked. Thanks. Why did you use <<< here? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---arithmetic-operations also can you write it as an answer? thanks!

Comment: @MonaJalal: `<<<` indicates that what follows is a ["here-string"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), which is provided to the utility on its standard input, followed by a newline. So `foo <<<"some input"` and `echo "some input"|foo` do essentially the same thing, but there are several advantages to not using a pipe. Also, it's shorter and more readable, once you get to know it.

Comment: Ah, too late for an answer - but @rici says it all in his comment.

Comment: This being said, hackerrank is not exactly a haven of best practices.